# AES/GCM Encryption on C# and decryption on Java fails with error "Tag Mismatch"

Tags: java, c#, cryptography, bouncycastle, aes-gcm

I have been trying to send data effectively between two applications. One is implemented in C# (Sender) the other in Java (Receiver). The sender has to encrypt data using the transformation "AES/GCM/NOPadding" with a 32-byte key while the receiver has to decrypt using the same parameters. Here is the sender encryption function in C# (using bouncy castle)

```
public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string msgId)
        {
            const byte GcmTagSize = 16;

            byte[] hashKey;
            byte[] secretKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msgId);

            Console.WriteLine(secretKey.Length);

            using (var hasher = SHA512.Create())
            {
                byte[] digestSeed = hasher.ComputeHash(secretKey);
                hashKey = new byte[16];
                Array.Copy(digestSeed, hashKey, hashKey.Length);
            }

            var keyParameter = new KeyParameter(hashKey);
            var keyParameters = new AeadParameters(keyParameter, GcmTagSize * 8, secretKey);

            var cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
            cipher.Init(true, keyParameters);

            var plainTextData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plainText);
            var cipherText = cipher.DoFinal(plainTextData); //bouncy castle 

            return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText);
        }
```

Here is the receiver decryption function in java

```
private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] message, SecretKey key) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NOPadding"); //NoPadding


        byte[] nonce = Arrays.copyOfRange(message, message.length - cipher.getBlockSize(), message.length);
        byte[] encryptedKycData = Arrays.copyOf(message, message.length - cipher.getBlockSize());


        System.out.println(doEncode(nonce));


        System.out.println(doEncode(nonce));
        GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, nonce);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, gcmParameterSpec);

        byte[] decryptedValue=cipher.doFinal(encryptedKycData);

        return decryptedValue;

    }
```

When I try to decrypt with the java decryption function I get the error

```
javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch
```

Struggling with this issue and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see where you are generating or retrieving the nonce in the C# code. Typically the nonce is 12 bytes for GCM and is placed at the front of ciphertext with the tag at the end. But you are copying 16 bytes from the end as your nonce.

Comment: You're right, it was an issue with the nonce. The implementation above didn't have that correctly implemented. Thank you for your hint.